# The file /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d from aws ec2 does not exist

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Other than that, I'm trying to find a file like the title within aws ec2, but it doesn't exist. I think I deleted it without knowing it. Is there any other solution when the file doesn't exist? Reinstallation is considered as a last resort.

Comment: Did the EC2 system have MySQL installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel you man and I really hate to be that guy but this is why we need backup. That being said, you can just recreate the directory manually and add a `mysql.cnf` inside. Typically, it only contains placeholder section for your mysql config with some license texts.

```
# Copyright (c) 2015, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2.0,
# as published by the Free Software Foundation.
#
# This program is also distributed with certain software (including
# but not limited to OpenSSL) that is licensed under separate terms,
# as designated in a particular file or component or in included license
# documentation.  The authors of MySQL hereby grant you an additional
# permission to link the program and your derivative works with the
# separately licensed software that they have included with MySQL.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License, version 2.0, for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301  USA

#
# The MySQL  Client configuration file.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

[mysql]
```

I don't know what else is in your config file but if you have custom settings, you can also add them by hand.

Usually, there is also a `mysqldump.cnf` inside `conf.d` with the following content

```
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
```

Comment: Thanks Jech Chua. I will try to reflect this opinion